# Redundant control flow jump statement and execution of jump statement

Tags: c#

unable to understand few things here:

1. On the goto statement in the below code, i am getting a compiler tip saying redundant control flow jump statement. What does it mean?
2. I am unable to understand, why, in output i get finally before the lbl text?

Thanks and please correct me my question if its wrong anywhere.

```
   class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
           try
            {
              Nullable<int> i = null;
              //i = 5;
              Console.WriteLine("i:" + i.HasValue);
              Console.WriteLine("i:" + i.Value);
            }
           catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
           {

             Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + e);
             goto lbl;  // A

           }
           finally
           {
             Console.WriteLine("finally");
           }
           lbl:
           Console.WriteLine("hi lbl");
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to avoid a finally block:

1. Kill the process
2. Kill the computer

However, normal code cannot skip a finally block.

As such, the unnecessary control flow statements is basically just that if you removed the `goto lbl` statement, the control flow would go the same way anyway. It will always execute the `finally` block, and *then* goto the label. Since there is no code after the `finally` block but *before* the label, then normal control flow without the `goto` would go this way anyway.

Comment: thank you. I have found your answer highly useful and satisfactory.